# Understanding for alternating functions

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$f$ is *alternating* if $f(v_1,...,v_n)=0$ whenever $v_i=v_j$ for some $i\neq j$.

Can you explain this definition more clearly?

Comment: The determinant is alternating.

Comment: @Mankind I did not understand the definition of alternating. Can you explain clearly?

Comment: $f(x, y)=x-y$, where $x, y$ belong to a vector space.

Comment: $f = 0$ is the simplest.

Comment: @WillM. What is the $f$?

Comment: @Kahler If $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are vectors from $V:=K^n$ and we let $f(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ denote the determinant of the $n\times n$  matrix having $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ as column vectors, then this defines a map $f\colon V^n\to K$. This map is alternating because whenever two column vectors are the same, the matrix is not invertible and the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I wrote it, $f = 0,$ that is, $f$ is the zero function (works if you are in _any_ vetor space).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is there a typo because you say that $f(v_1,...,v_n)$ denote determinant of the $n\times n$ matrix having $v_1,...,v_n$ as column vectors. Hence, ıt should be $n\times 1$ matrix, shouldn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Because ıt is just column vectors, isn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can you say that two column vectors are the same? I coulnd't see this.

Comment: @Kahler If for some $i\ne j$ we have $v_i=v_j$, then the $i$th column equals the $j$th column in the matrix having our vectors as columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition you give,

> $f$ is alternating if $f(v_1,...,v_n)=0$ whenever $v_i=v_j$ for some $i\ne j$,

is specifically used for *multilinear* functions, that is, functions which are linear in every argument. For such function it is equivalent to the following, more obvious definition:

> $f$ is alternating if it is changes sign whenever two arguments are exchanged.

To see how this works, let's look at a function with just two arguments, $f(u,v)$.

It is immediately obvious that for the second definition, for $u=v$ we get $f(\color{red}{u},\color{blue}{u})=-f(\color{blue}{u},\color{red}{u})$ (note that the colours are there to help understanding what happens, but the different-coloured variables still denote the same value, that is, $\color{red}{u}=\color{blue}{u}=u$). But $f(u,u)=-f(u,u)$ means $f(u,u)=0$.

For the other direction, we need to explicitly use linearity in both arguments. Due to linearity, we have
$$f(u+v,u+v) = f(u,u) + f(u,v) + f(v,u) + f(v,v)$$
But according to the definition you cited, $f(u+v,u+v)$, $f(u,u)$ and $f(v,v)$ all vanish, so that equation reduces to
$$0 = f(u,v) + f(v,u),$$
that is,
$$f(u,v) = -f(v,u)$$

Comment: where is the second definition?

Comment: @Kahler: In the second paragraph. The first definition in in your question.

Comment: @Kahler: I've now edited my answer; I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Kahler: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Other users have provided examples of alternating functions and I see you still have a question about what does it mean for a function to be alternating. A function $f(v_1,...,v_n) \in \mathbb{R}$ is said to be alternating if $f(v_{\sigma(1)},...,v_{\sigma(n)}) = \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot f(v_1,...,v_n)$ where $\sigma \in (S_n, \circ)$, $(S_n, \circ)$ is the symmetric group of $A \equiv \lbrace 1, 2, 3, \cdots \cdots, n \rbrace$ and $\textbf{sgn}(\sigma) = \pm 1$. I see your definition as more of a corollary of the above definition (I show this below) and this is probably why it was difficult to come up with non-trivial examples.

What the above definition means is that, no matter how you shuffle around the input variables, you always get the original functions value back, just with a $\pm 1$ in front. If $\sigma \in S_n$ then $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,..,n\}$ and so it shuffles the input variables around. Before moving on, let us define $\sigma (f) = f(v_{\sigma(1)},...,v_{\sigma(n)})$. Since $f$ is alternating, then $\sigma(f) = \pm  f$.

Recall that every permutation is a product of simple transpositions (i.e $\sigma = \tau_1 \cdots \tau_k$), and so to undo the shuffling, we take $\sigma^{-1} = \tau_k^{-1} \cdots \tau_1^{-1}$. Hence, $\textbf{sgn}(\sigma) = (-1)^k$.  Thus if $v_i = v_j$ and $j \not = i$ then $\sigma = (i,j)$ and $\sigma(f) = f = - f$ which implies $f = 0$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think in the third line, $\sigma \in S_{n}$ ?